# Spark: Association with remote system lost akka.tcp (disassociated)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am using Spark 1.3.0 with Hadoop/Yarn and I am having an error message which says

> WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkYarnAM@virtm2:51482] has failed, address is now gated
>   for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].

I read about it and found that setting the akka heartbeat interval to 100 would solve this problem:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Name");
conf.set("spark.akka.heartbeat.interval", "100");
```

Unfortunately, it does not in my case. The jobs fails with this error as cause after a few seconds I hit enter.

I submit the job with this command:

```
/usr/local/spark130/bin/spark-submit 
--class de.unidue.langTecspark.TweetTag 
--master yarn-client 
--executor-memory 2g  
--driver-memory 4g 
/home/huser/sparkIt-1.0-standalone.jar
```

The logs of the executing container on the nodes say the Application master got killed

```
5 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
```

I attempted to let a minimal example run, this one (it essential does nothing..just to see if it has the same problem.):

```
public static void main(String [] args){
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Minimal");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        JavaRDD<Integer> distData = sc.parallelize(data);
        sc.close();
    }
```

I get in the log again the Applicationmaster killed Error. Whatever is wrong here is not memory related, but I am having really difficulties to track this problem.

I have a mini-distributed setup with 4 machines for data/processing and 1 for the namenode.

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: your master is not running!

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur when master and slaves are not started properly. start master and slaves using `./sbin/start-all.sh` then submit your application.

Comment: I am using yarn in client-mode. If I run spark without yarn the problem does not occur from which I assume that there is no particular problem with the master/slaves.